# How to write php else in html

Tags: php

The else dosent work in this code and i have tied lot of things not just redirect()

```
<html>
<?php if($_SESSION['username']) : ?>
<?
echo "Hi, " .$_SESSION['username']. " | ";
?>
<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>
<?
else
redirect();
?>
<?php endif; ?>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to this style over using braces?

Comment: I would say its personal preference, as long as you are caching the byte-code the performance remains the same regardless.

Answer (score 8):

This should clear things up for you whilst using the alternative syntax: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

It should have a colon `:`

```
<?
else:
redirect();
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the alternative syntax gets you confused, you can always use the more familiar curly braces:

```
<?php if($_SESSION['username']) { ?>
    Hi, <?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?> | <a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>
<? } else { redirect(); } ?>
```

Or do it all in PHP:

```
<?php 
if($_SESSION['username']) {
    echo "Hi, " . $_SESSION['username'] . " | <a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
} else {
    redirect();
}
?>
```

I personally find those a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a special framework to construct the page? normally, what you output with PHP can be HTML as well, so no need to start/stop the scripting language and instead try something like this:

```
<html>
<?php 
if($_SESSION['username'])
{
    echo "Hi, " .$_SESSION['username']. " | ";
    echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
}
else
{
    redirect();
}
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

the else misses a ':'

```
<html>
<?php if($_SESSION['username']) : ?>
    <?
    echo "Hi, " .$_SESSION['username']. " | ";
    ?>
    <a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>
<?
  else:
     redirect();
?>
<?php endif; ?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a redirect then I would consider having that as the primary path through the code, that way it's clear at the top rather than buried 3/4 the way down.  Plus you can forget about it in the rest of the page.

E.g.

```
<?php
  if( ! $_SESSION['username'] ) {
    redirect();
  } else { ?>
  stuff...
<?php
  } >
```

Answer (score -2):

Use colon for else condition. Also check your php support `<?` or not. Try this:

```
<?php
    else:
    redirect();
    ?>
```

Comment: What PHP support are you talking about?

Comment: He's referring to the `<?` short_open_tag being enabled.  If short_open_tag is disabled and you use `<?` you would see PHP code output to the browser.